# Database not working when published my c# project

Tags: c#, database

I developed an application in C# using visual studio 2015. But when I published the application and run it on another system. It gives the following exceptions.

" A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessbile. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. Unable to locate a local database runtime installation.

Comment: Please provide some code or your connectionstring you are using. The error would also be helpful to know whats going wrong.

Comment: Did you check your connection string?

Comment: Here is the connection string, I am realizing that it would not work on someone else computer, but what to write instead of it?

string con_strr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\MAHMOOD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\childcare_software\childcare_software\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

Comment: did you get SQL Db hosting somewhere?

Comment: No, what is SQL Db hosting?

Comment: You need customize your Connection string based on Client. For project that must be used in small host/clients (not organization or ...) I prefer using MS Access, It's transfer is more easy and you don't have problems like this

Comment: I think for this customization, visual studio should have been installed on the clients computer. That way we could know which connection string would be appropriate on the clients computer.

Answer (score 1):

While publishing database, we need to cleanup the dev configurations a little further.

In the connection string check what is the Database server name on your client hosting environment and include that in: `Data Source="Client database host server name"`

Also instead of providing `.mdf` file ( as specified in your connection string with `AttachDbFilename='C:\Users...'`), better would be either generate the script from SQL Management studio in your local and run those in your client environment.

If it is by requirement to provide `.mdf` file then make sure the path to `mdf` file in hosting environment matches to what you give in your connection string.

Or else you can provide `mdf` file to client ask them to attach it to the hosted database server.

Often, `Integrated Security` might not be provided on host servers. So check the `userid/password` with your client on hosting machine to connect and update them in your connection string.

Hope some of these point might help you.